# how to send form data in a programmatic file upload in box api 2.0

Tags: box-api

Is the following a correct example of the form POST data in a file upload in the box api 2.0? The documentation says that the 'filename' form field is a string but when sending the post data in, say, python, you need to actually send the file contents in the post. So, is the content-disposition: form-data line below the correct way to name the 'filename' field and include the file contents?

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
Content-length: 142
Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=MY_API_KEY&auth_token=MY_AUTH_TOKEN

--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="test.txt"
Content-type: text/plain

testing box api 2.0

--AaB03x--
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: How he passes the folder_id?

Comment: He missing this value. At this moment, need add in post param with name "folder_id", not "parent_id"

Answer (score 0):

You mention Python, although you don't mention as being a requirement.
If you can use Ruby (another scripting language) you have a very nice lib to deal with Box API at the 2.0 version.

The lib is named [ruby-box](https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box) and in the readme you can find how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
-------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="82b.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

$base64_encoded_binary_file_content
-------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent_id"

123456789
-------boundary--
```

This is working code.