# Box File Upload API using Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, box-api

I have been trying out for a while using `Box 2.0 API` to upload a file from Objective C client to my Box folder. I've read a few posts from:

- [how to send form data in a programmatic file upload in box api 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372708/how-to-send-form-data-in-a-programmatic-file-upload-in-box-api-2-0?rq=1)
- [API 2.0 how to upload file with POSTMAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500241/api-2-0-how-to-upload-file-with-postman)

I've tried successfully using the `Curl`, as mentioned in the documentation, but always get a 404 when trying to create a `NSMutableUrlRequest`.
This is my code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content"];
    urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                  initWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                  timeoutInterval:30];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate];
    NSString *p = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BoxAuth api_key=%@&auth_token=%@",API_KEY,appDelegate.boxAuthToken];
    [urlRequest setValue:p forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *postBody = @"--AaB03x"
            @"content-disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"test.txt\";"
            @"folder_id=466838434"
            @"Content-type: text/plain"
            @""
            @"testing box api 2.0"
            @""
            @"--AaB03x--";

    NSData *data = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:data];
    [urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems that I see with the way you're constructing the postBody. Having newlines between string literals in your code simply concatenates them. You actually need to have carriage return and line feed to separate different parts of your HTTP body. Also, you mashed both of your form elements in one. The file and folder_id are two separate form elements. You could try something like this:

```
NSString *postBody = @"\r\n--AaB03x\r\n"
                      "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\n"
                      "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
                      "testing box api 2.0"
                      "\r\n--AaB03x\r\n"
                      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"folder_id\";\r\n\r\n"
                      "0"
                      "\r\n--AaB03x--\r\n\r\n";
```

I think that should work provided everything else is set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

It makes dealing with multipart forms much easier!

Comment: Please don't post api_key and auth_tokens on forum posts they are akin to posting your username and password.  I'm going to suggest that you edit your comment, pull out the details, and also do invalidate your auth-tokens on Box.